# Search result template is not working

Tags: wordpress

As wordpress page template hierarchy search.php is the page template to show search result. But I can't see the search result in search.php template file.Here is the search form:

```
<?php  get_search_form(); ?>
```

content of `searchform.php`:

```
<form action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ).'/search'; ?>" method="get" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
    <input class="search-box form-control border-secondary py-2" type="search" name="s" placeholder="Ask Your Question Here...">  
</form>
```

`search.php`:

## search.php page

I should see  **search.php page** when I search. but I can't see this. Whats wrong in my approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending the data to `/search` but there is no handler for your form

Please try changing your snippet to something like:

```
<form action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" method="get" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
    <input class="search-box form-control border-secondary py-2" type="search" name="s" placeholder="Ask Your Question Here...">  
</form>
```